# Web design tool to use with Foundation and Rails

Tags: web-development

This past semester in school, I started a rails project for a class. I am now going forward with this project to hopefully turn it into a full scale commercial site. I understand the rails (programming) side of the project well and the stuff I don't know how to do well, I can figure it out fairly easily. My huge problem is that I know absolutely nothing about web design / UI creation. I don't have much experience in HTML & CSS and I don't know where to start with the aesthetics on my site.

I would like to possibly use tools like Macaw or Google Web Designer, but I haven't been able to find a way to incorporate the Foundation Framework into these designers, as they seem to just use raw HTML and CSS.

So I was wondering if there is any good web design tools out there where I can load foundation style sheets / JavaScript into the tool so I can use them?